# Goodness of Fit (question about fitting procedure)

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

I have some vector with data $X$ that I suspect is exponentially distributed (after some visual evaluation).
I have fitted the exponential distribution to the data with the maximum likelihood estimator: $\lambda=(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i)^{-1}$ for $x_i\in X$. $X$ contains about 9000 observations.

My problem relies is in how to assess the goodness of the fit. I have tried the Chi-square method and the Kolmogorov-Smirnov method by computing the likelyhood of $X$ being an observation of the fitted distribution. When I do this the $p$ value is very very small; the test absolutely rejects the hypothesis. But visually the fit looks really good. So I think I'm doing something wrong.

Checking some literature I have seen the following method:

1. Fit the distribution with $X$, say we get a distribution $D_X$. Compute the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance of the fit.
2. Sample artificial data from $D_X$.
3. Compute the KS distance now between the sampled artificial data and $D_X$.
4. Repeat 2-3 many times to obtain distances $d_1,d_2...$.
5. Compare $d_1,d_2..$ with $d$.

But I don't really understand this method because it looks like we assess the goodness of the fit without using the original data $X$.

I wonder if anyone has some advice on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much data do you have? With a large data set, these tests will reject based on even small differences. What you have to ask yourself is whether  the fit is good enough for your application, which is quite possibly a different criteria than accept/reject your goodness of fit tests. You might be better off looking at effect sizes in operational regions.

Comment: Hi A. Webb and thank you. The vector $X$ has 9000 values. It looks good enough for my application but I would like to justify it if possible. Does the method I described from the literature make any sense?

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of this method is, though it appears to be constructing a confidence interval for the null hypothesis that $D_X$ is the correct distribution. Can you cite a reference? There is violation of the K-S assumption of independence when you estimate the model and test it on the same set of data. Bootstrapping can overcome this. The method you've described is a bootstrap, but I don't think its the correct one for addressing that issue, where I think you'd be sampling the original data.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes it makes sense what you say.
I found the method in a pdf online; there is no author specified.

Comment: Link? On second thought, I think what may be off here is step 3. It seems you'd want to take your sample and fit a _new_ (in this case) exponential distribution and do a K-S of your sample from 2 against _it_ rather than $D_X$. If this is correction for the flexibility in choosing the parameter of fit from the same data, then I think you'll even more likely reject.

Comment: I did not find that link again, but trying to find it I found some lecture notes in which the method is specified and apparently it is correct:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1b85/f2b451b8bbcbc9e5cfbfe317b0fd2464b2e9.pdf
The original source seems to be:
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02613687

Comment: Yes, in section 3.1 of that first link, the bootstrap is refitting for the K-S, the suspected missing part of step 3 above. Section 2.1 of the same  says for certain distribution families, exponential being one, the modified critical values do not depend on the initially estimated parameter -- they are scale and translation invariant. So, there should be a table of modified k-s critical values specific to exponential distribution that have been fit with the same data. Googling turns up an example, where as expected, the critical values are smaller, meaning you are even more likely to reject.

Comment: Yes, I guess I will try something bootstrapping from the original data $X$ as you first suggested. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind with null hypothesis significance testing (NHST) what you are actually testing is whether an effect is statistically *detectable* under the null hypothesis, not that its size is "significant" in the more typical modern meaning. Now also consider that NHST is often conducted with the null hypothesis being 0 effect, and it shouldn't be surprising that the null is rejected for *any* real world phenomena with enough data.

For example, let's say we have the null hypothesis that a given wheel is circular. If we measure a few dozen points with a crude ruler, we will likely not reject the null and happily keep rolling. But, if we precisely measure with a microscope at thousands of points, we will always eventually accumulate enough evidence to reject the null if our tools are sensitive enough. After all no real wheel is completely exactly circular. Even if it could have somehow been machined perfectly, gravity and temperature will still have deformed it.

This is analogous to your situation, where in the comments you've indicated that you have 9000 data points. This gives the NHST a lot of power to detect even small deviations. It's kind of like looking at that wheel under the microscope to see if it's perfectly round. What's the point? You should have known it wasn't perfectly round to begin with. The point is will the thing roll well enough? If we're talking about tires for go-charts there is going to be a completely different answer than roller bearings used in an MRI. Likewise, if your data comes from the real world, then of course it does not have a perfect exponential distribution. And even if you have all the reason in the world to believe the process that created it should be exponential, the real world likely has deformed it or its measurement somehow or other. The question is, is it good enough.

You need to specify what is good enough for your application and how to measure it. Perhaps the K-S statistic -- maximum distance between the ECDF and the hypothesized distribution is the most appropriate -- perhaps it's not. But, if you do use it, you should specify a different null hypothesis than the default of maximum distance of 0. Rather, specify that it is within your maximum tolerable distance of $t$, whatever $t$ is for your application. So your null becomes $|d| < t$ rather than the completely unrealistic $d = 0$.

The bootstrap method in the [link](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1b85/f2b451b8bbcbc9e5cfbfe317b0fd2464b2e9.pdf) you provided in your comments can help you develop this modification. It's intent is bootstrap corrected critical values for the problem of fitting distribution from the same data you are testing again. As noted in my comments, the procedure in the linked notes is similar to the one you have in your original post, but your step 3 is off -- you need to refit to an new $D_X^*$ at each iteration and measure against those rather than always $D_X$. With minor modification you also use this bootstrapping procedure to get estimates the critical values, or better, confidence intervals for a null specified within some tolerance range $|d| < t$ rather than precisely 0 difference $d = 0$.

Comment: Good answer and well put. Maybe you can help a bit with this one: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266574/indepence-of-observations-in-real-life-examples>
You seem to know a lot.